# Accessing another PHP application session data within Zend 1.12.20 on same domain

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, session-variables

I have stored **PHP Session** in **Core PHP Application**(www.domain.com), and want to use that session in **Zend** application(`www.domain.com/zend_app/`) on same domain.
In `$_SESSION` variable of **PHP** in **Zend**, I am getting only the session data set in Zend, not the session data which has been set in Core PHP application. Can anyone suggest how can i access session data of Core PHP in Zend Application?

Comment: This should work out of the box. Could you add some code to your question to show how you are adding data to the session in both places and how you're checking whether or not it's there?

Answer (score 0):

As a general best-practice tip with handling sessions across domains and subdomains, use a dedicated session handler. I would suggest an in-memory key-value store like Redis. You can set the default `save_handler` in php.ini to use Redis.

I suggest one of many excellent articles on the web, particularly [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-redis-server-as-a-session-handler-for-php-on-ubuntu-14-04) one. You should then be able to make calls to your Redis server or other session store e.g. memcached to retrieve the data.

Comment: The question was specifically about two applications running on the same domain.

Comment: It still applies. I wouldn't want to store sessions in files for any application - think about load balancing with an nginx proxy or even something rudimentary like a round robin with multiple servers. You may end up on a different machine without your session data from another. Same domain or not, I would advise production apps shouldn't have sessions stored by files with questionable permissions, maybe even on shared servers with others able to eavesdrop.